# buddypress get activity title

Tags: buddypress

i am trying to get activity title for each activity by using the following code. but it is repeating the activity title for each activity .

```
    <h2 class="posttitle">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php _e( 'Permanent Link to', 'buddypress' ); ?>
    <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?>
    </a></h2>
```

i Also tried using calling `bp_get_activities_title()` but it gives no result can some one help me out with this

Answer (score 0):

i believe that is because the_title() just prints out the title. try using the following in order to get the title.

```
<?php echo get_the_title(bp-activity->$ID); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late answer, but how and/or why would activities have a title? You could possibly get the text of the activity itself and use this as the "title" with

```
echo $activities_template->activity->content;
```

Perhaps there is another variable in there you might find useful. I suggest printing the array

```
print_r($activities_template->activity);
```

and see what's in it.

**EDIT: Though you better pray there is no HTML in ->content (or you can just strip the html out :] )**